# Testing elements inside unfriendly iframes with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, testing, iframe, phantomjs

Does anyone know if it possible to test for dom elements in unfriendly iframe inside phantomjs? If it is possible, how would someone do that?

I know that we need to set webSecurity to false, but other then that, I dont have any experience with iframes.

```
'web-security': false
```

Accessing iframes elements:

```js
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('url', function (status) {
   var _count = page.evaluate(function() {
        var matches = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
        var count = 0;
        [].forEach.call(matches, function(match) {
            var add = 0;
            try {
                add = match.contentDocument.querySelectorAll('div').length;
            } catch (x) {

            }
            count += add;
        });

        return count;
    });

    console.log(_count); // 0 - not true
    phantom.exit();

});
```

Running PhantomJS

```
 npm run phantomjs --web-security=false server/tests/unf.js
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"unfriendly"*? You can just switch to the frame that you want and do anything you want in there. You don't have to disable webSecurity to do that. http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-frame.html

Comment: Cross Domain, iframe has src.

Comment: What's the issue then? Can you give an example of such a frame as markup and how you tried to access it?

Comment: Do you know that `document` has only some meaning inside of [`evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)? You can't use that to switch to a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Do not run local phantomjs, phantomjs has to be installed globally.

```
npm install phantomjs -g
phantomjs --web-security=false server/tests/unf.js
```